# Create a tight frustum around a 3D model bounding volume

Tags: math, 3d, frustum, culling, glfrustum

## Tight frustum

I intend to create a tight frustum around a 3D model:

[image: Frustum schematics]

I have these variables:

- Inputs:

  - 3D model bounding box or bounding sphere or bounding volume.
- To be determined:

  - Eye distance and location.
  - Up vector.
  - Vertical field of view in degrees.
  - Near plane.
  - Far plane.
  - ...?

## Question

How can I determine my variables so that the frustum would be tightly surrounding the 3D model? I'm looking for some approaches, algorithms, or even keywords and terminology.

Looks like there is [Frustum Culling](https://learnopengl.com/Guest-Articles/2021/Scene/Frustum-Culling) approach to figure out if a bounding volume is on a frustum. But what I want is kind of reverse of that. I want to create a tight frustum around a bounding volume. I'd appreciate any hint or help.

Comment: My eventual goal is to take a screenshot of the 3D model. I'm currently taking the screenshot, but the 3D model doesn't fit my final image tightly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estimating the eye distance by max dimension of b-box and the `fovy` angle might help:

[image]